# If Else, What to do when something random happens?

Tags: vbscript

I'm currently making a simple AI (kind of anyways). I have a bunch of `If..Else` in place to respond to what they input but I'm looking for the syntax to have a `MsgBox` appear when they type in something that hasn't been programmed. So if they typed something like, "dasdsafasfresxdf" that wasn't in the if else it would run a `MsgBox` command.

Comment: Edit your question and post your code !

Answer (score 2):

Normally the `Else` branch is for handling things that don't match a condition.

```
If inputVar = "expected value A" Then
  'do some
ElseIf inputVar = "expected value B" Then
  'do other
ElseIf ...
  ...
Else
  MsgBox "Unexpected input."
End If
```

If you're always comparing the same variable you can also use a [`Select Case`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ef9w614) statement instead of multiple `ElseIf` branches:

```
Select Case inputVar
  Case "expected value A"
    'do some
  Case "expected value B"
    'do other
  Case ...
    ...
  Case Else
    MsgBox "Unexpected input."
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider a `Select Case` statement:

```
Select Case(input)
 case "hi" : response = "hello"
 case "bye": response = "goodbye"
 '...etc
 case Else : MsgBox "Sorry, I didn't understand " & input & ".  Can you rephrase?"

End Select
' do whatever with the response here...
```